# How can I make my animation 'pulse' each element rather than odd ones?

Tags: css, sass

So far my animation 'pulses' each odd element and then switches to even elements.

I want to achieve the effect where each element in the sequence pulses separately one by one in order.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
.pulse-through {
    span {
        display: inline-block;
        @include animation('pulse 0.4s alternate infinite ease-in-out');

        &:nth-child(odd) {
            animation-delay: 0.4s;
        }
    }
}

/* KEYFRAME ANIMATIONS */
@include keyframes(pulse) {
    to {
        @include transform(scale(0.8));
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
}
```

My includes are just the regular css transforms and animations but for each browser, to simplify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
.pulse-through {
    span {
        display: inline-block;
        @include animation('pulse 0.4s alternate infinite ease-in-out');

        @for $i from 1 through 20 {
            // limit the amount by some count, or try another way
            // if that doesn't work
            &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
                animation-delay: ($i * 0.2s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There must be a more efficient way, I thought about doing that but what if there are less/mroe than 20 elements? Plus that code doesn't work, nth-child expressions can't take $i

Comment: Sorry, forgot to interpolate the selector. Updated, should work now. And, if you incorporate some JS to it, it'll be easier - but CSS/SASS only... no better way that I know of. You could increase the 20 to any arbitrary number, but remember they won't all be visible on screen anyway, you might wanna find the right number